# Return type of Angular new HttpClient when options are set, how to use it?

Tags: angular

I'm struggling with an issue with the new HttpClient, it works if I don't pass any HttpOption to the client, but it gives compilation error if we pass some option object

For instance

Working code:

```
  terminateSession(key: string): Observable<boolean> {    
    return this.http.get<boolean>(
        this.baseUrl + '/user/invalidateSession/'+ key)
               .pipe(
                  catchError(this.handleError('terminateSession'))
               );
  }
```

Non-working code:

```
   terminateSession(key: string): Observable<boolean> {  
    // adds authentication headers to this.httpOptions
    this.addHttpHeaders();
    return this.http.get<boolean>(
        this.baseUrl + '/user/invalidateSession/'+ key,
        this.httpOptions)
               .pipe(
                  catchError(this.handleError('terminateSession'))
               );
  }
```

The error the ts complier is giving is:

```
ERROR in src/app/_services/user-session.service.ts(45,5): error TS2322: Type 'Observable<boolean | HttpProgressEvent | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<boolea...' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.
  Type 'boolean | HttpProgressEvent | HttpSentEvent | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpResponse<boolean> | HttpUs...' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
    Type 'HttpProgressEvent' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Now I understood that the .get method has different signatures as stated by official documentation:
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get

And that the signature in question is:

```
get<T>(url: string, options: {
headers?: HttpHeaders | {
    [header: string]: string | string[];
};
observe: 'events';
params?: HttpParams | {
    [param: string]: string | string[];
};
reportProgress?: boolean;
responseType?: 'json';
withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<HttpEvent<T>>
```

But I cannot find any example of usage of this kind of observable Observable> i just need to return an Observable where in this simplest case T is boolean.

Can you please give me a solution to make the code returning Observable or a sample of usage (e.g. a subscribe with arrow function to get the boolean value) of Observable>.

I know also that best solution is to use an interceptor to pass authentication headers, but please provide also a solution for this case as we also need to pass other custom headers, differently request by request

Thanks in advance

Comment: *But I cannot find any example of usage of this kind of observable Observable<HttpEvent<T>> I just need to return an Observable<T> where in this simplest case T is boolean.

Can you please give me a solution to make the code returning Observable<boolean> or a sample of usage (e.g. a subscribe with arrow function to get the boolean value) of Observable<HttpEvent<boolean>>.

I know also that best solution is to use an interceptor to pass authentication headers, but please provide also a solution for this case as we also need to pass other custom headers, differently request by request

Comment: You need to add map pipe/operator to turn the response into a boolean

Comment: try setting `{responseType: 'text'}`